# unity : making a power meter for a shooting game

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am making a game where i require a power meter. i am using drag and shoot method, and have LineRenderer as my trajectory. basically when u click and drag on the screen the ball moves in the direction it’s s dragged (just like bow and arrow). i want to display a power meter too but some how not able to achieved it. i have few approaches but they don’t give what i want. can you please have look and suggest what am doing wrong. thank you

````
    {
        ChangeAni();

        if (onGround && ballMoveable)
        {

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                startPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                startPoint.z = 2;
                    
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                 currentPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                 currentPoint.z = 2;


                 tl.RenderLine(startPoint, currentPoint);
                
                force = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.x - currentPoint.x, minPower.x, maxPower.x), Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.y - currentPoint.y, minPower.y, maxPower.y));
                float powerDisplayX = Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.x - currentPoint.x, 0, power);
                float powerDisplayY = Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.y - currentPoint.y, 0, power);
                powerDisplay = powerDisplayX + powerDisplayY;
                Debug.Log(powerDisplay);

                //powerDisplay = force.x + force.y * power;
                //if (powerDisplay < 0)
                //{
                //    powerDisplay = -powerDisplay;

                //}


            }

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                endPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                endPoint.z = 2;

                //force = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.x - endPoint.x, minPower.x, maxPower.x), Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.y - endPoint.y, minPower.y, maxPower.y));
                rb.AddForce(force * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                tl.EndLine();
                Debug.Log(force * power);
            }

        }```
````

Comment: `they don’t give what i want` .. what do you want? What is happening instead?

Comment: @derHugo, i want to display the power value on a text field so that player can increase or decrease power by dragging before he fires.

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer to the `powerDisplay` part.

Note that you are clamping both vector components individually so you might get a vector bigger than expected (with a maximum magnitude of `sqrt(power^2 + power^2) = 1.41 * power` ;)

.. you might rather want to use [`Vector2.ClampMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.ClampMagnitude.html)

> Returns a copy of `vector` with its magnitude clamped to `maxLength`.

like

```
powerDisplay = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(startPoint - currentPoint, power);
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but clamping the magnitude gives me 2 values x and y.